# Which mosque to choose for Jumma if both are next to eachother?

Tags: masjid, jumuah

If two mosques are very close to eachother and both accessible easily, how can we decide which mosque to go to for jumma prayers? Especially if one was created to differentiate from the first one (as explained here in another question: [Can United Nations troops make mosque at their Camp? Even if another mosque exists?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/49022/can-united-nations-troops-make-mosque-at-their-camp-even-if-another-mosque-exis))

Thanks.

Comment: The bigger or the older one it seems opinion-based... Earlier scholars hold the opinion jumu'ah must be prayed in only one mosque.

Comment: I will choose, which have better KHATEEB, so I can learn something. Otherwise the bigger one.